# Previewing Google Actions on a Home Device

Tags: actions-on-google

Is it possible to test out an API.AI agent on my own Home device or is this only available via the Web Simulator?

I have an agent test running and previewing ok via the web simulator but would like to test without having to register and deploying it as its not ready.

I have looked through here  https://developers.google.com/actions/tools/testing but doesn't seem to mention testing voice interaction on a home device on your same google account.

It would seem very odd not being able to test out on actual hardware.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Testing on your Google Home device "just works" if your Google Home and API.AI are both using the same account.

In API.AI in the "Actions on Google" integration, make sure you have the Invocation Name set[image] and click on the "Preview" button. If you get the message saying it is ready, you should be able to access it on your Home within about 30 seconds.

Then you just need to start the action on your Home by saying something like "Hey Google, talk to Preview" and the Assistant will reply "Ok, here is the test version of Preview".

Make sure the Invocation Name used here is the same as one that you have setup for your welcome intent. If you're using one that is "too close" to another (existing) action or too close to one of the built-in direct actions, it may not be picked up correctly and you should consider a different name.

Comment: Hi, I tried that, and while is works using the invocation voice command on the simulator I couldn't get it to work on the home device.
Does it take a while to activate on the device or do you need to turn something on to allow preview apps?

They are using the same google account.

Comment: I find it takes under 30 seconds. Occasionally I will ask and it doesn't respond, but it works fine on the second try moments later. You may also be running into a conflict with another Action. I've updated my answer with some of these suggestions, but you may also want to update your original question with what message you're getting back when it doesn't respond, or give an idea what your invocation name is so others can test it out.

Comment: Got further but now It seems to be that you can't currently test actions in British English.
I tried setting the home device language to US English but then just doesn't recognise the command.

Comment: That is, very unfortunately, correct right now. It sounds like your invocation name is a British English term? Can you clarify or post an answer about how you "got further"?

Comment: I seemed to get further by previewing the app and setting to 24h while at work and then trying the action on the device when I got home.
I'm unsure if it took a while to become active before or if Google just had an issue at the point in time.

Answer (score 0):

Google have updated the Actions on Google and api.ai since this post.

The new details on testing are here:
[Testing and Publishing](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/testing-deploying)

Comment: Can I do test my api.ai Actions in Mobile on Google app

Comment: Please don't provide a 'one link' answer. Use them as a reference for your solution.